# How to automatically resubmit form

Tags: php, html

My site uses a combo of sessions and get/post.

When user hits back button, it says "confirm you want to resubmit form" or a similar message, depending on the browser. Then the user has to also refresh the page.

How can I make it automatically resubmit form. I don't want users seeing this message and getting stuck when they hit back.

I have PHP + HTML

Comment: have you tried something so far??

Comment: you can not stop the browser's back button event.

Comment: resubmitting the form will only allow lots of duplicates. use redirection after submitting the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use get method in post method resubmit message is appear and if you want to use post method then on server page use header such as `header('location:index.php')` and change index page that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question, but do reconsider.

POST actions should change the state of the server. GET actions should be transparent. If you're using a POST to submit data to commit to a database or launch nuclear missiles or whatever, the resubmit warning exists for a reason: imagine your embarrassment when you launch two nuclear missiles, but was only trying to launch one.

GET actions, on the other hand, by their specification, should never meaningfully impact the world, so the resubmission is safe. If there is something the user is allowed to go back to, it's a GET page. A POST page should not be returnable-to using the back button (or rather, the user should be made aware of it).

If you have to suppress this warning, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I figured it out.. so basically my DB was returning results and i put the results into a $_SESSION[result number]=result value
and i make user choose result number. then on next page i match up number with value. so user never sees the value, they just see the result number. i was basically trying to make it so they don't see the value in my DB which is kind of secretive. yes, i know it's complicated... hard to Xplain. but im glad i thought of it. wow how did i pull that one off? i got lucky!!!

Comment: basically everything is in a session var, which is exactly what i want.